# How to install Adobe Photoshop CS4 without discs

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How to install Adobe photoshop without original discs, install from copied files only?

Comment: which Creative Suite ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Probably CS4, assuming the "$" in the title was a typo of "4", on a U.S. keyboard, while the shift key was down, as opposed to brief commentary on the price of the package :)

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This is a good question!  (I have no @#$% clue where my original disks are.  I'm sure they're in a box in the back bedroom ***some***where, but I can't begin to imagine where.)

Answer (score 2):

You won't get a working installation by copying the binaries from /Applications and will want to re-run the proper installer or get assistance from Adobe since this is a licensed product that has proper vendor support for reinstalling the licenses if you should need to move it from one computer to another.

Answer (score 2):

If you for some reason lost the installation files, you can download the trial here: http://prodesigntools.com/download-adobe-cs4-and-cs3-free-trials-here.html

Once installed, simply register with the credentials you received upon purchasing the product. If you do not have your registration details either, I would suggest chatting with an Adobe representative to discuss your options: http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/find-serial-number.html (simply click the Chat Now button at the bottom of the page).